Jenkins code coverage plugin: Approve absolute path
I'm using the coverage plugin in Jenkins to show coverage results.
I've configured it like this:
recordCoverage qualityGates: [[
            criticality: 'NOTE', 
            integerThreshold: 80, 
            metric: 'LINE', 
            threshold: 80.0]],
            tools: [[parser: 'COBERTURA', 
                     pattern: 'coverage_*.xml']]

Since my jobs are not executed directly on the agent, but in a SLURM cluster, the jenkins workspace is different from the location where the actual files are stored. This because a problem when the plugin tries to stores the files:
[Coverage] [-ERROR-] Errors while resolving source files on agent:
[Coverage] [-ERROR-] Removing non-workspace source directory '/tmp/scratch/mydir' - it has not been approved in Jenkins' global configuration.
[Coverage] [-ERROR-] - Source file 'file1.py' not found
[Coverage] [-ERROR-] - Source file 'file2.py' not found
[Coverage] [-ERROR-] - Source file 'file3.py' not found
...
[Coverage] [-ERROR-]   ... skipped logging of 105 additional errors ...

I have found this option in Jenkins: http://[my-jenkins-url]/manage/configureSecurity/ in the section 'Prism syntax highlighting'. I filled in some directory names, however it is not working.
This is my configuration
My questions:

Where can I find the option to approve this directory in Jenkins?
Does the approving accept wildcards (for different tests, the exact location of files might be different, however the root is always the same)?


Super ugly, but since there are no other answers, here is one:
We run the build in a docker container, so we mount it into /data.
The cobertura coverage file contains that /data path.
So when we run readCoverage in jenkins, it fails the same way as OP.
=> I just added a ugly sed to replace the path:
sh("sed -i 's#<source>/data/frontend</source>#<source>${WORKSPACE}/frontend</source>#' frontend/output/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml")

